# numpy: dispatch nansum

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Why does `np.nansum` not apply the redefinition in this subclassing?

```py
import numpy as np
class xarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, arr):
        obj = np.array(arr).view(cls)
        return obj
    def sum(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 4
    def nansum(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 99

a = xarray([1., 2, 3])
a.nansum()     # 99
np.sum(a)      # 4
np.nansum(a)   # 4  #!? I expect 99
```

The attribute method `a.nansum()` works as expected. But while `np.sum` applies its redefinition, `np.nansum` does not.
Both, [sum](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2092-L2094) and [nansum](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2410c6d0a63cb56455fc9ab6affcf1a776c82134/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py#L559), apply the `array_function_dispatch` decorator.
How can I understand this? And what is a solution so that `np.nansum` behaves as I intend?

I have numpy 1.18.5.

Comment: The linked `nansun` code doesn't do any dispatching.  It replaces any `nan` with 0 and calls `np.sum`

Comment: In the `np.sum` code, I also can't see any magic. I thought it comes from the decorator. Thus, what is the difference?